# Video introduction to linux command line

Tags: command-line

I've been using ubuntu for like 3 years as my main os. I've used terminal many many times but never have I deeply understand it. I run commands, I'm familiar with the basic ones, but i want to dig deeper. Is there any video introduction(i like to lay back and watch tutorials instead of reading books) to novice-intermediate to advanced command line?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The linux command line is called `bash` (**B** ourne **A** gain **SH** ell), you can [search for it on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=bash+learning) if you want. I used to watch some tutorials about scripting a while ago, here are some of my favorite:

## Bash Introduction

- [Introduction to the BASH Shell (Linux Terminal) & File Manipulation Commands](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6pp82CVQfQ)
- [Basic Bash Scripting Lesson #1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VRvnfzJngY4)
- [Basic Bash Scripting Lesson #2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pr5mGQpTbic)

## Accelerated learning

- [Accelerated Bash scripting for beginners Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dv9IEBbkVVE)
- [Accelerated Bash scripting for beginners Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sH-1HKY6Guk)

## Advanced bash

- [Advanced BASH](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOghzsTlNg8)
- [Intermediate and Advanced: 20. Bash Shell Scripting](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjSZAlW5F0U)

Nowadays, I don't really like video lessons, I can read faster than hear someone teaching, if you want some reading material:

- [BASH Programming - Introduction](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html)
- [Ubuntu Bash guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting)
- [Bash guide for begginers](http://tille.garrels.be/training/bash/index.html)